# PyGame wont register keydowns

Tags: python, macos, pygame, osx-yosemite

I have installed pygame on my macbook and it seems to be working however it doesnt seem to be registering specific keys

For example

```
    RunGame = True    
while RunGame:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            RunGame = False
        if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
            Direction = 'West'
```

The quit code runs just fine however the left key is not registered. When i print the event the only event that is printed when i press any key is the key up and key down event so i cant do anything with specific keys. Am i using pygame wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RunGame = True    
while RunGame:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            RunGame = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                Direction = 'West'
```

You forgot the `event.type` and remember it is `event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:`. you had `event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:`

Comment: Sorry i should have mentioned that i have tried this. Although technically should it make a difference?

Comment: You didn't read clear enough. I'll make an edit. Also too whoever the down voter was care to elaborate on your reasoning?

Comment: Dude im sorry youre the best! Thank you so much!